# Kaggle kernel is not using GPU

Tags: scikit-learn, gpu, kaggle

I have a training dataset of shape (120k+, 14) and I'm trying to use GridSearch for Random Forest with 2500 trees.

Just wondering why my Kaggle notebook never uses the GPU even when CPU usage is over 100%???

Do I have to import something or add some code to start the GPU?

[image: screenshot of Kaggle, showing 0% GPU being used]

Answer (score 1):

GPUs are only helpful if you are using code that takes advantage of GPU-accelerated libraries (e.g. TensorFlow, PyTorch, etc.) mostly for training deep learning models. scikit-learn, which you're using here, doesn't support GPUs ([and it probably won't](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support)). Unless you want to use a different framework, I'd recommend turning the GPU off.